# Does electron field exist?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

We know, that one-particle states can be earned from relativistic fields, which can be interpreted as functions determined on Minkowski space-time. Field must satisfy some conditions, by which we classify them as massive/massless, spin/helicity, etc. Electron can be represented as one-particle state of bispinor field, which satisfy Dirac equation. But what is the electron field? Does it exist? Or it is only convenient method for describing, for example, scattering processes?

Comment: Do "forces" exist, or are they merely a convenient method for describing, for example, everything about the macroscopic dynamics of systems of particles?

Comment: @joshphysics . My question is something like this: electromagnetic, gravitational (etc.) fields are fundamental fields, and corresponding quants are interaction carriers. But we can't talk about electrons as interaction carriers. Also, in classical limit we still can talk about EM field as about field, but we can't (?) talk about spinor field as about field, because on classical level electron is only particle in this case.